# Ruby Algorithm for categorization of products

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a ruby algorithm that will work as follows:

- User creates "search queries" that assign products to categories based on certain criteria (i.e. if product has "red" in the name, script assigns the product to category id #20, if product has "glass" in the title, script assigns the product to category id #40, etc etc). Products can belong to multiple categories
- Every so often, the script will run and assign products to their respective categories, and push updated categories to Ecommerce platform via API

I am struggling because I cannot figure out the most efficient way to do this. I want to limit the number of API requests to make to the ecommerce platform, and only "push" the updated categories when they have actually changed.

Initially I thought I would run through each product one by one, see which rules/categories it matches to, then push the new product categories to the ecommerce platform only in the event that there is an actual change. The problem with this approach is that I have to run through 3000 products every time a new rule is created.

The alternative would be every time a new rule is created, to run through all the rules again and update the categories in the local database, but then how could I check if the categories actually changed?

Any pointers would be much appreciated...I am storing the categories in the database as an array (i.e. 29,20,38,27) for each product.

Comment: This is a bit of a vague question, but if it was me I will start by learning this [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this.

```
key_to_category = { "red"=>1, "blue"=>2, "green"=>3, "pink"=>2 }
keys = key_to_category.keys
  #=> ["red", "blue", "green", "pink"] 
cats = key_to_category.values.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 

products = [
  "Red and Green Gummies",
  "Sky-Blue Thingamajigs",
  "Dead Fred",
  "Green Glue",
  "Blue and Green Whatchamacallits"
]

r = /
    \b                    # match word break
    #{Regexp.union(keys)} # match any key
    \b                    # match word break
    /x                    # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /
      \b
      (?-mix:red|blue|green|pink)
      \b
      /x 

products.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |prod, h|
  prod.downcase.scan(r).each { |key| h[key_to_category[key]] << prod }
end
  #=> {1=>["Red and Green Gummies"],
  #    3=>["Red and Green Gummies", "Green Glue",
  #        "Blue and Green Whatchamacallits"],
  #    2=>["Sky-Blue Thingamajigs", "Blue and Green Whatchamacallits"]}
```

Then step through the hash to do the update.

Alternatively, step through the product table, obtain `product_name`, compute

```
product_name = "Red and Green Gummies"
key_to_category.values_at(*product_name.downcase.scan(r))
  #=> [1, 3]
```

and then update categories 1 and 3.

Comment: I own one of the products, which I find very useful, as I'm always looking for a pen or pencil.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The products are in the database as records (rails & postgres)..Would that make any difference in approach? Especially considering I have 3k+ products...

Comment: Also this gives me each category with its products..Unfortunately I cannot update the product categories in API by category. I must update by updating the single product...

Comment: I made an edit at the end that may be more useful to you. btw, 3k+ products seems miniscule, considering that Amazon sells over 200,000.